# How do I use the grey formatting in a comment?

Tags: support, comments, formatting, code-formatting

Someone showed me (by editing my question for me) how to make some of your

```
text show up grey to show it is code.
```

Now I need to know how to do it in a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using the wrong character.  I thought the directions said to use the apostrophe character ( **'** ) but they said to use the backtick character ( **`** ) which was a subtle difference that I wasn't catching.

Now I can `present console input/output` in comments.

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to migrate this to meta, as recommended by @pomsky.

Comment: It won't let me accept the answer for two days.  Do I just wait or does someone else need to accept it now on my behalf?

Comment: Everyone needs to wait two days before they can accept their own answer.

Comment: Thank you for editing my answer, @karel.  Good improvement.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the purpose of this format is not to achieve "grey background" but to provide a means to present console input/output.

Comment: I'm a semi-literate computer user, but I had never heard of a "backtick" until I had this problem.  I did my due diligence and looked up the [formating rules](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) in the help forum, but it would never work for me since I was using the apostrophe.  In an international forum where lots of English words have different meanings, there might be an advantage to being more precise and expressly stating that the character is a backtick but is not an apostrophe.  My two cents.